# Select slugs from TABLE_A that are not already in TABLE_B MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following mySQL code written in PHP

```
SELECT * FROM $photos;
```

I then have some code which adds the photo slug to a database into table 2. The photos table can grow large, so I want the SELECT above to only SELECT photos where the photo hasn't already been added. There's no timestamp or anything to work from, i.e something like

```
SELECT * FROM $photos INNER JOIN $slugs WHERE $photos. 'slugs' <> $slugs . 'slugs'
```

Am I going in the right direction here, INNER join is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using a `LEFT JOIN`, which tends to be much faster than the `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM $photos
LEFT JOIN $slugs ON $photos.slugs = $slugs.slugs
WHERE $slugs.slugs IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are going in the right direction but I think you can better use a **[Left Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)** instead of using a `where` clause.

Try like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM $photos LEFT JOIN $slugs ON $photos.slugs = $slugs.slugs
WHERE $photos.slugs IS NULL;
```